# Netezza, how take only record recently update in a table?

Tags: database, select, netezza

there is a function in netezza Database for take only record recently update?

I try with:

```
select *
from 
  myTable
where 
last_modified_timestamp > current_timestamp - '5 minute'::interval
```

but dont work  ERROR:  Attribute 'LAST_MODIFIED_TIMESTAMP' not found.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a column that specifies the order of inserts/updates or the date/time of inserts/updates?

Comment: no..i dont have a column like this

Answer (score 0):

Netezza does not track row level modification metadata automatically. You would have to implement that yourself using a timestamp column and ETL logic to update it properly.